# WSTOPSIG(status) == 22 & WTERMSIG(status) == 9; Where do these numbers come from?

Tags: c, fork, waitpid

I'm looking over an implementation of esh (easy shell) and cannot understand what signals are 22 and 9 in this case. Ideally there is a more descriptive constant, but I cannot find a list.

Comment: Yes ideally. If the sources belong to you, change `9` to be `SIGKILL` and `22` to be `SIGTTOU`.

Answer (score 5):

The list of signals and their numbers including the two you're seeing is actually specified by POSIX.1-1990, and can for example be found [if you scroll down a little in this manual page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html).

```
SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
SIGTTOU   22,22,27    Stop    tty output for background process
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SIGTTOU 22,22,27    Stop    tty output for background process
SIGKILL  9         Term Kill signal
```

Those are signal numbers.  The meanings are platform dependant - these are the Linux ones.

See:

```
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl7_signal.htm
```

A signal is sent to a process via the kernel. In this case `SIGTTOU` says a background process tried to write to the tty.  This causes a kernel issue, which raises that signal.  By default the result of that signal is to terminate the process.